# How to use conditional comments correctly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Can I write all the CSS for IE bugs in 1 conditional load?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

If I make 1 conditional comment with LT IE 9, can I write the CSS for IE7 and IE8 inside or do I need to make 2 different stylesheets?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you put inside of that conditional comment will be interpreted by the corresponding browsers. That means that you can put multiple link-tags inside of a single conditional comment. But in your case, all of them will be interpreted by IE 5,6,7 and 8. If you need a separate stylesheet for every version, you will also need a separate conditional comment for every version.

But you should definitely take a look at this blog post:

http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

This method can help you cleaning up all those conditional comments.

**edit:**

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Foo!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
  font-size:2em;
}

.ie h1{
  /* will only apply to IEs - but all of them */
  font-size:1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Can i use one class for all? <!--[if  IE]>      <html class="ie"> <![endif]--> and put that in front in the things i need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different stylesheet for each version of IE, you will also need to make a different conditional for each one; linking to a unique stylesheet. `lt` Stands for 'less than', alternatively, there is also `lte`, which is 'less than or equal'.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link href="ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the same stylesheet for **all** versions of IE less than or equal to 9, use:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link href="ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thank you for the fast answer. what are the best practices to use conditional comments? To use 1 conditional comment or 2 -3 of them? or use classes?

Comment: @user2852447 If it has to be browser specific, I would go with the individual conditionals. Otherwise, if it is applicable to all versions, go with the single conditional.

Comment: Given that [IE 10 doesn't support conditional comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/), all versions of IE less than, and including, 9 can omit the condition and simply target `<!--[if IE]>`